# Vacuum decay and Coleman-de Luccia bubbles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, cosmology, resource-recommendations, cosmological-inflation

Can someone suggest me some good and detailed books (or notes) on the problem of [vacuum decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum) and Coleman-de Luccia bubbles?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read Coleman's book "Aspects  of Symmetry"? Its the notes of some of his   Erice lectures. He has a good account of the basic bubble theory, but does not, I think, discuss the effects of gravity.